# Laravel - How to force date format to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8 project, I have this code:

Model

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'start_date',
    'end_date',
];

protected $dates = [
    'start_date',
    'end_date'
];
```

View:

```
  <td>
     <input type="date" name="start_date[]" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" class="form-control start_date" min="{{Carbon\Carbon::now()->firstOfYear()->format('Y-m-d')}}" max="{{Carbon\Carbon::now()->lastOfYear()->format('Y-m-d')}}">
  </td>

  <td>
     <input type="date" name="end_date[]" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" class="form-control end_date" min="{{Carbon\Carbon::now()->firstOfYear()->format('Y-m-d')}}" max="{{Carbon\Carbon::now()->lastOfYear()->format('Y-m-d')}}">
  </td>
```

With this, I expected the date to display as dd/mm/yyyy, but it still comes as mm/dd/yyyy

See it below:

[image: date format]

Some systems display it as dd/mm/yyyy while others as mm/dd/yyyy

However, I want it to be:

dd/mm/yyyy

How do I resolve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The date input UI generally varies from browser to browser; see [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Browser_compatibility) for further details. The displayed date format will differ from the actual value — the displayed date is formatted based on the locale of the user's browser, but the parsed value is always formatted yyyy-mm-dd.

You can get and set the date value in JavaScript with the input element's value and valueAsNumber properties. For example:

```
var dateControl = document.querySelector('input[type="date"]');
dateControl.value = '2017-06-01';
console.log(dateControl.value); // prints "2017-06-01"
console.log(dateControl.valueAsNumber); // prints 1496275200000, a UNIX timestamp
```

This code finds the first  element whose type is date, and sets its value to 2017-06-01 (June 1st, 2017). It then reads that value back in string and number formats.

For more info, please check [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date).